# How to add prefix to suggestions in evil-mode?

Tags: spacemacs, evil, prefix-keys, which-key

Spacemacs has a way to add prefix descriptions with `(spacemacs/declare-prefix ...)`. However, some `evil-mode` keybindings are lacking prefix descriptions. For example, in evil-mc `g` `r` is the prefix for multiple cursors. However, after waiting for suggestions from `g`, there is no prefix description for `r`. So my question is:

How do I declare a prefix for an evil keybinding (in spacemacs)?

Comment: You can find how to do this in the multi-cursors layer (see the `which-key-add-keymap-based-replacements` form after the `:init` keyword, after doing `SPC h SPC evil-mc`), as it has already been defined for `evil-mc`. However, indeed for some reason it isn't working. But you can see that normally this should work by looking at the "gs" prefix for evil-easymotion (see `SPC h SPC evil-easymotion`).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the comment by @dalanicolai to the question.

In principle, to add a custom prefix, add
`(which-key-add-keymap-based-replacements evil-motion-state-map "<prefix>" "<string>"`
when the package is initiated where "" are the prefix keys and "" is the description of the prefix to be shown.

That is, in the `packages.el` in the folder of the relevant layer.

```
(use-package <package-name> 
  :init
  <HERE>
)
```

In the example of `evil-easymotion` this has already been done. In the file "emacs.d/layers/+spacemacs/spacemacs-editing/packages.el":

```
(defun spacemacs-editing/init-evil-easymotion ()
  (use-package evil-easymotion
    :defer t
    :init
...
    ;; Provide proper prefixes for which key
    (which-key-add-keymap-based-replacements evil-motion-state-map
      "gs"  "evil-easymotion")
...
)
```